# How can I change the group titles in a pandas grouped-by boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3),
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
df['X'] = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                     'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'])
df['Y'] = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A',
                     'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'])
boxplot = df.boxplot(column=['Col1', 'Col2'], by=['X', 'Y'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to change the two labels `Col1` and `Col2`, I have tried to pass the argument `labels=['Left label','Right label']` (to the matplotlib core function https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) but with no luck:

```
boxplot = df.boxplot(column=['Col1', 'Col2'], by=['X', 'Y'], labels=['Left label','Right label'])
```

gives me the error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions of labels and X must be compatible
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, because boxplot here returns a NumPy array of axes, you can use each element of this NumPy array and set_title:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3),
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
df['X'] = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                     'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'])
df['Y'] = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A',
                     'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'])
ax = df.boxplot(column=['Col1', 'Col2'], by=['X', 'Y'])

ax[0].set_title('AAA')
ax[1].set_title('BBB')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3),
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
df['X'] = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                     'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'])
df['Y'] = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A',
                     'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'])
axes = df.boxplot(column=['Col1', 'Col2'], by=['X', 'Y'])
titles=['Left label','Right label']
for ax, title in zip(axes,titles):
    ax.set_title(title)
```